# Type 'ContentView' has no member 'setNeedsDisplay'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
func sheetClosed(){
   
    ContentView.setNeedsDisplay()
    
}
```

I keep getting 'Type 'ContentView' has no member 'setNeedsDisplay'. How can I fix this?

Comment: ```.setNeedsDisplay()``` is a UIKit part not for SwiftUI. Why you want this?

Comment: i want to refresh my content view, to fetch my new api data

Comment: You can not use by this way. Please add some more details so easy to answere.

Comment: i have a sheet where I post data to my api, after I close the sheet I want to refresh my view for a new api request in my main view

Comment: The sheet has already onDismiss completion block. Call your request in onDismiss block.

Comment: yeah, but when I try to call self.hours (hours is the name of the array with api data) it will throw an error that self isn't in the scope

Comment: Please add code in post

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with @state properties in your ContentView. SwiftUI is declarative, and refresh the view when your @state properties change in that case @state property need to be your viewModel array with the data to display. In your case, for an approximation you could use your DTO objects (objects that retrieve from your API) as viewModels (entity objects to be displayed by the View) but It's not a clean way. Set the objects in your property when you get it and automatically the view will be refreshed

Please SwiftUI behaviour in check it: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Here you have another tutorial

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui

Vote up, if it's clarify you.

Have a good day :)